# authorization doesn't work yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to do:
when user authorized go to home page
when user not authorized go to Login page
but now when I put (correct) user email and password that always refresh login page and doesn't log in into system.

**User(ActiveRecord)**

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public function setPassword($user_password)
    {
        $this->password = sha1($user_password);
    }
    public function validatePassword($user_password)
    {
        return $this->user_password === sha1($user_password);
    }
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return self::findOne($id);
    }
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {

    }
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }
    public function getAuthKey()
    {

    }
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {

    }
}
```

**Login Model:**

```
class Login extends Model
{
    public $user_email;
    public $user_password;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_email', 'user_password'],'required'],
            ['user_email','email'],
            ['user_password','validatePassword']
        ];
    }
    public function validatePassword($attribute,$params)
    {
        if(!$this->hasErrors())
        {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if(!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->user_password))
            {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Пароль или пользователь введенны не верно');
            }
        }
    }
    public function getUser()
    {
        return User::findOne(['user_email'=>$this->user_email]);
    }
}

 ?>
```

**SiteController(only login function)**

```
public function actionLogin()
    {

        if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
        {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        else {
            $login_model = new Login();
            return $this->render('login',['login_model'=>$login_model]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can say it for all problems at stackoverflow,it's not an answer.

Comment: No you are right, its called a Comment. `givemeanswer` yea sure

Comment: It's not work because you do not call it anywhere. Noanswer, Let's check again your tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting username and password  is not enough  you should also perform a login

```
public function actionLogin()
{

    if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
    {
        return $this->goHome();
    }
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post())) {
        // you should perform  login 
        \Yii::$app->getUser()->login($model->user, $this->rememberMe ? $model->module->rememberFor : 0);
        return $this->goBack();
    }

    else {
        $login_model = new Login();
        return $this->render('login',['login_model'=>$login_model]);
    }
}
```